# aprstable with robust standard errors for model with singularities

Tags: r

I am trying to create a table of estimation results with robust standard error using the `aprstable` package. However, because my model has singularities that aren't easily avoided (they come from overlapping factors with hundreds of levels), `aprstable` refuses to provide the table I am trying to produce. Here's a working example (adapted from a [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335621/r-calculate-robust-standard-errors-vcovhc-for-lm-model-with-singularities)):

```
library(sandwich)
set.seed(101)
dat<-data.frame(one=c(sample(1000:1239)),
                two=c(sample(200:439)),
                three=c(sample(600:839)),
                Jan=c(rep(1,20),rep(0,220)),
                Feb=c(rep(0,20),rep(1,20),rep(0,200)),
                Mar=c(rep(0,40),rep(1,20),rep(0,180)),
                Apr=c(rep(0,60),rep(1,20),rep(0,160)),
                May=c(rep(0,80),rep(1,20),rep(0,140)),
                Jun=c(rep(0,100),rep(1,20),rep(0,120)),
                Jul=c(rep(0,120),rep(1,20),rep(0,100)),
                Aug=c(rep(0,140),rep(1,20),rep(0,80)),
                Sep=c(rep(0,160),rep(1,20),rep(0,60)),
                Oct=c(rep(0,180),rep(1,20),rep(0,40)),
                Nov=c(rep(0,200),rep(1,20),rep(0,20)),
                Dec=c(rep(0,220),rep(1,20))) 
model <- lm(one ~ two + three + Jan + Feb + Mar + Apr + May + Jun + Jul + Aug + Sep + Oct + Nov + Dec, data=dat)
summary(model)
model$se <- vcovHC(model)

library('apsrtable')
apsrtable(model, se='robust')
```

executing this code produces

```
> apsrtable(model, se='robust')
Error in s$coefficients[, 3] <- tval <- est/x$se : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
In addition: Warning message:
In est/x$se :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

As far as I can tell this error occurs because `length(sqrt(diag(model$se)))` is 14 while `length(coefficients(model))` is 15, i.e. there are more coefficients than there are standard errors on the diagonal of their variance-covariance matrix (see also the [relevant bit of source code in the `aprstable` package](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/R/apsrtable.R?view=markup&revision=17&root=apsrtable&pathrev=17)).

Is there any easy way to fix this? Insert NA rows and columns into the variance-covariance matrix in the appropriate places before passing it to `apsrtable()` perhaps? Something more elegant?

Comment: Excellent question by RoyalTS. I think your analysis of the error is spot on. I confirm that I have the same error. Would be great if this could be fixed in a new version of apsrtable.

Comment: FWIW, I've since moved on to the `stargazer` package, which works better in many regards and is better maintained. I haven't tried if it suffers from this problem yet, but if you're stuck, perhaps it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was an easy fix — coef(model) returns the thing with NA, but coef(summary(model)) returns the coef of the summary. I'll submit an update to cran soon, but the package at https://github.com/malecki/apsrtable is updated.