# stargazer() for models with singularities

Tags: r, regression, sweave, knitr

I try to create a table of regression results using the `stargazer` package. 
Unfortunately `stargazer`refuses to create the table because of singularities.
As these singularities come from overlapping factors with many levels they are not easily avoided. That´s why I am looking for an alternative solution
 Here's a working example 
[adapted from a related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335621/r-calculate-robust-standard-errors-vcovhc-for-lm-model-with-singularities) :

```
library(sandwich)
library(stargazer)
set.seed(101)
dat<-data.frame(one=c(sample(1000:1239)),
            two=c(sample(200:439)),
            three=c(sample(600:839)),
            Jan=c(rep(1,20),rep(0,220)),
            Feb=c(rep(0,20),rep(1,20),rep(0,200)),
            Mar=c(rep(0,40),rep(1,20),rep(0,180)),
            Apr=c(rep(0,60),rep(1,20),rep(0,160)),
            May=c(rep(0,80),rep(1,20),rep(0,140)),
            Jun=c(rep(0,100),rep(1,20),rep(0,120)),
            Jul=c(rep(0,120),rep(1,20),rep(0,100)),
            Aug=c(rep(0,140),rep(1,20),rep(0,80)),
            Sep=c(rep(0,160),rep(1,20),rep(0,60)),
            Oct=c(rep(0,180),rep(1,20),rep(0,40)),
            Nov=c(rep(0,200),rep(1,20),rep(0,20)),
            Dec=c(rep(0,220),rep(1,20))) 
model <- lm(one ~ two + three + Jan + Feb + Mar + Apr + May + Jun + Jul + Aug + Sep + Oct + Nov +    Dec, data=dat)
summary(model)
stargazer(model)
```

Because of singularites I get the  Error: subscript out of bounds. Do you have any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This problem has been fixed. The more recent versions of stargazer (from 3.0) should have no problem with your example.